# What did you do that day? (two months ago in the middle of the process)

Tags: meaning, grammar, past-tense

Two similar situations.

The first one: I started painting a picture ten days ago. I haven't finished it yet. Everyday I've been painting my picture for half an hour.

The second one: I started painting a picture **three** months ago. I finished it **one** month ago. It took me **two** months to finish it. Everyday over the period of **two** months I paited my picture for half an hour.

If somebody asks me: What did you do yesterday/that day (in the middle)? **What should I asnwer?**

A: What did you do yesterday?

B: *(in addition to other things)* I painted my picture for half an hour. ***or*** I was painting my picture for half an hour.

and

A: What did you do that day? (two months ago in the middle of the process)

B: *(in addition to other things)* I painted my picture for half an hour. ***or*** I was painting my picture for half an hour.

Comment: I think most people would say "I worked on my picture/painting for half an hour every day". "I painted my picture" usually refers to the complete task.

Comment: According to your words they meant the entrie book [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-uW_KheiEc&ab_channel=EasyEnglish) 0:49 - 0:52 and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfVTb3AaE0U&ab_channel=%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD) 1:04 - 1:09. It's a little strange that he said that William Shakespeare had written the entire book (that day). Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The second one is not idiomatic English. If they mean _the_ William Shakespeare, he wrote plays, not books, and in any case we wouldn't say 'he wrote a book' to mean that he spent some time working on whatever he was currently writing. It's true that people do sometimes say "I read a book" when they only had time to read part of it.

Comment: He is a native English speaker from America. Is he mistaken using "He wrote a book" for not completed action? What about the first example?

Comment: Native speaker or not, I find it very unnatural. My last sentence refers to the first link. (If the character is a child, she could possibly have read an entire children's book in a morning.)

Answer (score 2):

> 1: I started painting a picture ten days ago. I haven't finished it yet. Everyday I've been painting my picture for half an hour.
>
> 2: I started painting a picture three months ago. I finished it one month ago. It took me two months to finish it. Everyday over the period of two months I painted my picture for half an hour.

> If somebody asks me: What did you do yesterday/that day (in the middle)? What should I answer?

1: A: What **were** you **doing** yesterday?

You: “I **was painting**.

2: “What **were** you **doing** between September and October?”

You: “I **was painting** a picture.”

1a: A: What **did** you **do** yesterday?

You: “I **painted**.”

2a: “What **did** you **do** between September and October?”

You: “I **was painting** a picture.” (The continuous is used as the action was not complete at the time referred to.)

2b: “What **did** you **do** in November?”

You: “I **finished painting** a picture.”

You will note that answers are usually (but not always) given in the same verb form as the question.

Comment: Is it OK to say "I wrote a book / I read a book / I drew a picture / I built a ship / I knitted a sweater" about yesterday if I didn't finish it yesterday? For instance: Leonardo Da Vinci painted the Monalisa for four years. On one of the days in the middle he just painted it for a while and postponed continuation for another day.
A: What did you do yesterday?
B: I read a book. (I neither started nor finished yesterday)

Comment: We cannot answer questions without context. It is not possible to over-stress the importance of context in English - in Russian it may not matter, but it is vital in English. Thus, *Is it OK to say "I wrote a book / I read a book* cannot be answered because there is no context. In the example where there is context Leonardo could say "I read a book" and this makes no comment about whether he finished it.

Comment: **1a:** A: What did you do yesterday?

You: “I painted.” A: What did you paint? What should I answer if I didn't finish it yesterday?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov  Why would that even matter? The question asked is in the simple past without any progressive aspect to it. You must therefore answer the same way. It doesn't matter whether you finished painting: you slept since then and are not painting now as the question is asked. Even if you were still doing so and hadn't stopped, you would have to answer in the simple past. You can't answer a question asked using the perfective aspect of completion with a verb in the imperfect or incomplete aspect.

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov You seem to be looking for absolute rules on the use of verb forms. You are wasting your time. There are no rules in English: there is only guidance. Some guidance may look like a rule... it isn't. You should accept all the answers as guidance and apply them using context and your knowledge of English.

Comment: _What did you do yesterday? You: “I painted.” A: What did you paint? What should I answer if I didn't finish it yesterday?_ Answer "I was working on my picture of [a landscape in Italy]" or "I'm currently painting/working on [a landscape in Italy]."

Comment: Greybeard, I am pretty sure that it's you who are wasting your time trying to "correct" learners and rebuking them for looking for absolute rules which they don't do. The OP wasn't looking for absolute rules. If you can't address a certain issue properly, don't bother going into pontificating.

Comment: What did you do yesterday? You: “I painted.” A: What did you paint? What should I answer if I didn't finish it yesterday? Answer "I spent some time painting X, yesterday"

Comment: @user1425 Many thanks for taking time out of your busy schedule to give a few of your precious thoughts - you can only imagine how I appreciated them. I can inform you that learners **do** look for absolute rules, and each learner should be told not to do this. As far as "pontificating" is concerned, the verb seems strangely inappropriate: the Pope's words are said to be absolute, and yet I end *"You will note that answers are **usually (but not always)** given in the same verb form as the question."*

Comment: I understand that producing false sentiments of gratitude is part of your culture, so let's count that you have fulfilled your duty well. I am a learner myself and I am fed up with unsubstantiated claims of those who feel the urge to aggrandize themselves that learners are always to blame for the things "clever-clogs" can't explain. AS for "pontificate" to speak in a pompous or dogmatic manner:
Did he pontificate about the responsibilities of a good citizen?

Comment: @user1425 *I am fed up with*. I suggest you take your frustrations out on someone else and somewhere else - that or take cold showers.

Comment: Greybeard I suggest that you keep your advice to yourself. What frustration are you talking about? I am excited that my message hurts your vanity.

Comment: Your vicarious opinions are not supported by the OP.